# Cant access database from pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, nginx

I`m using postgresql database on my web server (ubuntu + nginx) and it works with backend app. I want to connect remotely using pgAdmin
but it always throw this error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection timed out(0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "ip" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

[image: connection error]

I already add to my *pg_hba.conf* this line:

**host    all   all    all   password**

and also add to *postgresql.conf* line:

**listen_addresses = '*'**

netstat -nlt does next result, and it`s enough in tutuorials i found, but still cant access my database

[image: netstat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, it works as well after this command:

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Open file named **pg_hba.conf**

```
sudo vi pg_hba.conf
```

and add this line to that file

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password

**restart your server**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: I did as you shown above, but result is still the same